# Efficient client-side table filtering in ASP.NET Core web app without pagination

Tags: asp.net-core

I have created an ASP.NET Core web app template and added a Razor page that successfully queries a database and displays the results in a table. However, the client has requested that the table should not have pagination. They want all values to be visible in the table and also want an input field to filter the data.

Initially, I thought of implementing a JavaScript method in the output HTML to handle the table filtering. However, I encountered two issues: filtering based on cell values was unexpectedly slow, and this approach did not provide all the filtering features required.

Subsequently, I decided to utilize APIs and treat the Razor pages primarily as a templating engine, moving most of the logic to JavaScript (similar to my experience with Express/Node.js). This approach showed promise, as the page loaded quickly, data was downloaded via the API, and filtering based on an array was fast and efficient. However, I faced challenges when testing APIs that involved form file uploads and encountered other issues with this approach.

Now, I am reconsidering my options and exploring how to effectively filter a table in a more conventional ASP.NET Core web app setting. Refreshing the page every time the user types a filter is one approach, but it seems inefficient. As a relative newcomer to web programming, my experience has mostly been with single-page apps and simple APIs.

To summarize, I would appreciate guidance on the best way to implement in-place filtering for a server-generated table in an ASP.NET Core web app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To summarize, I would appreciate guidance on the best way to implement
> in-place filtering for a server-generated table in an ASP.NET Core web
> app.

Based on your requirement and description, I have tested the scenario using [asp.net core filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-a-search-box) from the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0) and according to my test I think its faster then jquery table filter and other conventional filter.

Here is my test result output:

[image]

[image]

Let's have a look in practice, how I simulated the test along with complete demo:

Model:

```cs
public class Products
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        public string? ProductName { get; set; }
        public int SupplierID { get; set; }
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string? QuantityPerUnit { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public Int16 UnitsInStock { get; set; }
        public Int16 UnitsOnOrder { get; set; }
        public Int16 ReorderLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```cs
public IActionResult Index(string searchString)
        {
            ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = searchString;

            var products = from pro in _context.Products
                          select pro;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                products = products.Where(m => m.ProductName!.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower())
                                       || m.QuantityPerUnit!.ToLower().Contains(searchString.ToLower()));
                return View(products);
            }
           
            var productList = _context.Products.ToList();
            return View(productList);
        }
```

**Note:** In order to simulate filtering I have used filter on ProductName and QuantityPerUnit property based on your context you could always modify it.

View:

```cs
@model IEnumerable<Dotnet7TableFilterDemoApp.Models.Products>
<div class="form-row">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="AddNewProduct" class="btn btn-success">Add New</a>

            </td>
            <form method="get" action="/FilterDemo/Index">

            <td style="padding-right:760px">
            </td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Search for..." name="SearchString" value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"]" aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="btnNavbarSearch" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </td>
            </form>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SupplierID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CategoryID)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QuantityPerUnit)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitPrice)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UnitsInStock)
            </th>
            <th>
              Actions
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SupplierID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CategoryID)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.QuantityPerUnit)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitPrice)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UnitsInStock)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="DetailsProduct" class="btn btn-primary" asp-route-ProductId="@item.ProductID">Details</a> |  <a asp-action="EditProduct" class="btn btn-warning" asp-route-productId="@item.ProductID">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** Although, your scenario is completely arbitrary in regards of developers preference, however,you could try above approach in order to deal with your scenario. You can get [more details here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/sort-filter-page?view=aspnetcore-7.0#add-filtering-functionality-to-the-index-method)